# Code coverage shows if-branch as missed but removing it leads to error

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, code-coverage, test-coverage

I am testing code with if-branch

```
fVal => {
    if(!fCache[idxF]) fCache[idxF] = {}
    fCache[idxF][idxCb] = fVal
}
```

which is [declared as "missed" by Coveralls](https://coveralls.io/builds/23880418/source?filename=index.js#L259).

However, if I remove that if-line, 
[the tests fail complaining about undefined prop](https://travis-ci.org/dmitriz/cpsfy/jobs/543281694#L467):

```
fCache[idxF][idxCb]=fVal;
                   ^
TypeError: Cannot set property '0' of undefined
```

This is precisely the error corrected by the if-branch.
Then why is it declared as "missed" in the coverage?

---

ADDED.
Here is the failing test:

```
test('ap over single CPS function', t => {
    const cpsFun = cb => cb(42)
    const cpsNew = ap(cb => cb(x => x*2))(cpsFun)
    cpsNew(t.cis(84))
})
```

and the relevant pieces of the code being tested:

```
const ap = (...fns) => cpsFn => {
  let fCache = {},
    argsCache = {}
      ...
    fns.forEach((f, idxF) => f(...cbs.map((cb, idxCb) =>
      fVal => {
        if(!fCache[idxF]) fCache[idxF] = {}
          ...
      }
    )))
  }
  return cpsNew
}
```

Comment: Hi @Dmitri Zaitsev, could you show the code that is testing the `fVal` method?

Comment: @mgarcia I have added the failing test and the function code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is a bit hard to understand BUT based on the content of your question I am guessing that you do not understand how code coverage works for conditional branches.

"if" statement is resulting in 2 branches: condition true and condition false. If your test operates only on data which has condition evaluated to "true" then your coverage is exactly 1 out of 2 branches (which I believe is what the report tells you).

To get 100% coverage for that line you have to have 2 execution passes over that line - one with condition evaluated to true and one with condition evaluated to false.

Comment: Yes, I misunderstood it, thank you for clarifying, I have added the missing test and released the update :)
https://www.npmjs.com/package/cpsfy